# set current year in select box in freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a select box in my freemarker page in which year are coming from data database

```
<select id = "years" name = "years">
    <#list getYears as year>
        <option value = "${year.years}">${year.years}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

Suppose value are coming 2009,2010,2011,2012,2013
 but I want the select value should be 2011 ie. the current year how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<select id="years" name="years">
    <#list years as year>
        <option value="${year?c}"<#if (year == .now?string("yyyy"))> selected="selected"</#if>>${year?c}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

I assume the `years` variable is a collection of the possible years.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
<option value="${years.year}" <#if years.year == actualyear>selected</#if>/>
```

with setting `actualyear` somewhere in your sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

The more updated (since Freemarker 2.3.23) way to do it would be with then ?then operand

```
<select id = "years" name = "years">
    <#list getYears as year>
        <option value = "${year.years}" ${(year.years == thisyear)?then('selected', '')}>${year.years}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

As another answer stated you would have to assign thisyear earlier in the code:

```
<#assign thisyear .now?string.yyyy />
```